# Calling Spring Bean from the EJB Session Bean

Tags: java, spring, ejb

I want to call my Spring bean from my EJB Session Bean. Here is an example scenario that I want to achieve.

#### Spring Interface:

```
public interface ReqSpring {
    public String processMsg(String msg);
}
```

#### Spring Bean:

```
@Component
public class ReqStringImpl implements ReqSpring{

    public String processMsg(String msg) {
        return "Msg ["+msg+"] is processed";
    }
}
```

#### EJB Interface:

```
@Remote
public interface EjbService{
    String echo(String msg);
}
```

#### EJB Session Bean:

(please notice that I have used `@Autowired` over a Spring object)

```
@Stateless(name = "EjbWS", mappedName = "EjbWS")
@WebService(name = "EjbService", portName = "EjbServicePort")
public class EjbServiceBean implements EjbService {

    =====> @Autowired
    =====> private ReqSpring reqSpring;

    public EjbServiceBean() {
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String echo(@WebParam(name="msg")String msg) {
            // This is printing null
        System.out.println("ReqSpring = "+reqSpring);
        return reqSpring.processMsg(msg);
    }
}
```

My Application failed to load the `ReqSpring` object from my EJB and always generating `NullPointerException`. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject a `Spring` Bean into a `EJB` like that because the `EJB` is not managed by the `Spring` container. Anyway, by using the `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor`, you will be able to do it. Try with this annotation :

```
@Stateless(name = "EjbWS", mappedName = "EjbWS")
@WebService(name = "EjbService", portName = "EjbServicePort")
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class EjbServiceBean implements EjbService {

    @Autowired
    private ReqSpring reqSpring;

    public EjbServiceBean() {
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String echo(@WebParam(name="msg")String msg) {
        System.out.println("ReqSpring = "+reqSpring);
        return reqSpring.processMsg(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it says `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance`

Comment: Your error is probably somewhere else, can you post the stacktrace